# how can i get an access to the elements of array in the class

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a problem which I don't know how to solve. I have a class. This class has two arrays. I would like to get access via properties. How can I do it? I tried to use indexers, but it is possible if I have only one array. Here what I want to do:

```
public class pointCollection
{
    string[] myX; 
    double[] myY;
    int maxArray;
    int i;
    public pointCollection(int maxArray)
    {
        this.maxArray = maxArray;
        this.myX = new string[maxArray];
        this.myY = new double[maxArray];           
    }
    public string X //It is just simple variable
    {
        set { this.myX[i] = value; }
        get { return this.myX[i]; }            
    }
    public double Y //it's too
    {
        set { this.myY[i] = value; }
        get { return this.myY[i]; }            
    }
}
```

With this code, my X and Y are only simple variables, but not arrays. 
If I use indexers, I get access only to one array:

```
    public string this[int i]
    {
        set { this.myX[i] = value; }
        get { return this.myX[i]; }            
    }
```

But how can I get access to second array? 
Or I can't use property in this case? And I need only use:

```
    public string[] myX; 
    public double[] myY;
```

Comment: Can you use an array of Tuple<String, Double> ?

Comment: is it possible to use array with different type of data?

Comment: Why store x and y separately? A struct like `Point` could leave you with ony one array and indexer would work, no?

Comment: separate because different types: X - like string, Y - like double

Comment: If your intent is to store a string and double that are related to each other, a Tuple<string, double>[] would best fit your needs. As @user467384 said.

Comment: @user467384, please write down simple example with using Tuple<String, Double>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got it right, you need some kind or read/write-only wrapper for arrays to be exposed as properties.

```
public class ReadWriteOnlyArray<T>{

    private T[] _array;

    public ReadWriteOnlyArray(T[] array){
        this._array = array;
    }

    public T this[int i]{
        get { return _array[i]; }
        set { _array[i] = value; }
    }
}

public class pointCollection
{
    string[] myX; 
    double[] myY;
    int maxArray;

    public ReadWriteOnlyArray<string> X {get; private set;}
    public ReadWriteOnlyArray<double> Y {get; private set;}

    public pointCollection(int maxArray)
    {
        this.maxArray = maxArray;
        this.myX = new string[maxArray];
        this.myY = new double[maxArray];           
        X = new ReadWriteOnlyArray<string>(myX);
        Y = new ReadWriteOnlyArray<double>(myY);
    }
}
```

and usage

```
 var c = new pointCollection(100);
 c.X[10] = "hello world";
 c.Y[20] = c.Y[30] + c.Y[40];
```

Comment: Why not just make the array property a protected set and be done with it? Your wrapper class doesn't add or remove anything.

Comment: @Xcelled194 Array instance has a lot of methods in addition to indexer, like Resize(), for example. The trick is to only left indexer available outside of the class.

Comment: @dmay ahh, right, Forgot about those :). But either the question or your answer should be reworded to state that explicitly, for future searchers.

Comment: ...Not to mention that his whole data structure probably needs to be rethought... but I digress...

Answer (score 1):

An example with Tuples.

```
public class pointCollection
{
    Tuple<String,Double>[] myPoints;
    int maxArray;
    int i;
    public pointCollection(int maxArray)
    {
        this.maxArray = maxArray;
        this.myPoints = new Tuple<String,Double>[maxArray];
    }
    public Tuple<String,Double> this[int i]
    {
        set { this.myPoints[i] = value; }
        get { return this.myPoints[i]; }            
    }
}
```

And to access the points you do...

```
pointCollection pc = new pointCollection(10);
// add some data
String x = pc[4].Item1; // the first entry in a tuple is accessed via the Item1 property
Double y = pc[4].Item2; // the second entry in a tuple is accessed via the Item2 property
```

Answer (score 0):

The closest you'll come without either changing your data structure or moving to methods is to make a property that returns each array, much like you did in your first code block, except without the [i].

Then, you do `var x = instanceOfPointCollection.MyX[someI];` for example.